# Programatically turn on and off databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a text box declared in xaml that uses databinding to a string property. How do I disable and then re-enable binding in code?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you meant "on and off", not "off and off"...

Comment: yes! sorry about that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BindingOperations.ClearBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearbinding.aspx) to remove a binding, and [BindingOperations.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx) to add it back in.

Comment: Looks like I can't really actually turn bindings on and off, but that seems good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work or not, but you could try calling [FrameworkElement.SetBinding()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273.aspx), and pass `null` for the second parameter.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it's a wrapper around BindingOperations.SetBinding, which says it will throw if the binding is null.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx